# Ajax Upload popup window not showing

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajax-upload

I am new to Ajax Upload and use http://valums.com/ajax-upload js file to cater for my upload file function. As i try to click the button for ajax upload...the pop up window to select file is not showing so i was unable to select file. Below is my button and code to trigger ajax upload.

```
<button class="pbutton btn-glossy-black" id="browseFile">Browse</button>


var upload = new AjaxUpload('browseFile', {
            action: jq_main_url + 'candidates/upload_attachment/' + main_folder_name,
            name: 'upload_file',
            data:{ 'countchecklist': 0},
            
            onComplete: function(file, response) {
                try {
                    var json = JSON.parse(response);
                    if(json.status == 'OK'){
                        alert('Complete');
                    } else {
                        core.jq_message(messageLevel, json.message);
                    }
                } catch(e){
                    core.jq_message(messageLevel, e.message);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: absolutely no information on that link ... so, how would we possibly know if you're doing something wrong

Comment: This is the link to the js file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bGSh3UoIKCXBolQyXCMI8s2NvTcV_xla/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no thanks - any link to documentation - not trawling through thousands of lines of code to see if you're doing it right

Comment: the link to the documentation is dead.

Comment: so, that code is dead - does anything appear in teh browser console when you press the button? note: looked at the code - `click` event is not captured, so, not sure how the code would possibly do anything ... you must've found SOME documentation, how else do you know that the first argument is an id, and that there's an `onComplete` method, and an `action` property etc